# How to prevent data time travel?

Tags: ros, timestamp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community.

I have some trouble in stereo camera data logging that some old data pushed after newer one.
[image: Figure of timestamp]

The way to save this data is like this: prepare empty list and push new data in each subscription and then save this list as csv.
How can I prevent this problem in a real situation?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275007/how-to-prevent-data-time-travel-?/) by [k_totoro](https://answers.ros.org/users/32221/k_totoro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try out the time sequencer message filter http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Time_Sequencer .  It looks like you want a buffer size to handle 3 seconds of messages.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0